# Output not getting as intened

Tags: java, printstream

I'm trying to read the file "ab.txt" and saving its content in "Output.txt" Kth times,so i'm suppose to get the content of input file K times in output file,but i'm getting only once whereas it is printing on console Kth times.

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class PrintStreamTest1
    {
       public static void main(String... l)throws IOException
       {
         int k=0;
         long avgTime=0;

        while(k<100)
        {
          long startTime=System.nanoTime();
          String s;
          Scanner fin=new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("ab.txt")));
          PrintStream output=new PrintStream("Output.txt");
          while(fin.hasNextLine())
          {
             s=fin.nextLine();
             System.out.println(s);
             output.print(s+"\n");
          }

          avgTime=avgTime+((System.nanoTime()-startTime)/10000000);
          fin.close();
          output.close();
          k++;
        }

        System.out.println("\n "+ avgTime+"ms");
       }    

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong constructor as you can see in the Javadoc :

> **PrintStream(String fileName)**
>   ...
>   **fileName** The name of the file to use as the destination of this print stream. **If the file exists, then it will be truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

You should open the file associated with the `PrintStream` in append mode if you don't want the content of that file overwritten in each iteration of your loop :

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Output.txt",true));
```

Alternately, just open the file once before the loop and close it once after the loop.

Comment: It should be on output stream `PrintStream output=new PrintStream("Output.txt");` not inputstream

Comment: @Sanjeev You are correct. I got confused by the input file. Will fix that. Thanks

Comment: No Problems .. it happens :)